# Guzzle - External File "passthrough"

Tags: php, guzzle

I need a way to load a large file from an external URL and upload it to a different destination without actually temporarily saving it locally. The upload is handled by an external package that accepts either a resource or a StreamInterface as the source. I have looked through the guzzle documentation but can't come up with a suitable solution.

So far I am stuck with something like this:

```
# Download
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://host.com']);
$resource = fopen('tmp_file', 'w');
$stream = GuzzleHttp\Psr7\stream_for($resource);
$client->request('GET', '/test.zip', [
    'sink' => $stream,
]);

# Upload
$uploadHandler->upload($stream);
```

That does unfortunately not work whatsoever. The file is being downloaded in full before the upload is being started. The destination also does not receive a usable file - i am not able to see what exactly it receives, but it is either empty or corrupt.

So, to summarize, it would be ideal if the file is being "passed through" (to the upload) as it's being downloaded. It would also be okay if there would be a small local buffer file.

Is this doable at all?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried streaming the file using curl. I am writing this in here so additional testing might be needed but something as follows:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://remote.server/file_handler.php");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pass");

// to return the result as a string and not output it directly
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, true);

// This is the remote file and if it is a stream you will need it's content length
// meta_data will provide you with this
$file = 'http://host.com/test.zip';
$fp = fopen($file, "r");
$meta = stream_get_meta_data($fp);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $meta['unread_bytes']);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);

curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
fclose($fp);
```

As a more server intense operation you may also take a look at the ftp service provided by php: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php and more precisely something like **ftp_append** or **ftp_put**.

But my suggestion would be to first try with the above script.

P.S

the **$file** variable indicates the remote file as you said *http://host.com/test.zip* and the remote server is the string inside the **CURLOPT_URL**. In theory, at least, you are passing the stream you are reading from one remote server to another remote server.

P.S

This way you can add headers to fopen on a remote file.

```
$options = [
    'http' => [
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header'=>"Accept-language: EN\r\n ANOTHER-HEADER: test=test"
    ]
];

$defineContext = stream_context_create($options);

$fp = fopen('http://host.com/test.zip', 'r', false, $defineContext);
```

You man refer to this for more details: https://www.php.net/stream-context-create

Comment: Unfortunately this does not answer the question in any way. it's not just about downloading the file. As mentioned, I need to pass it through to the upload handler (either as a resource or a StreamInterface) but without storing the whole file locally.

Comment: You are not "downloading" the file. You are using fp to open the remote file as a stream ( you can use a bunch of functions here ) and then using curl to directly send it to your remote server handler - named **remote server** ( ```http://yourremote.handler``` ).

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your approach. Could you please integrate the source file/url (which should be passed through), e.g. https://host.com/test.zip and the call to the upload handler (which expected either a resource or a StreamInterface) `$uploadHandler->upload($stream);` Thank you

Comment: I can't use fopen() for the source file. And as mentioned, the file should be passed through to a specific method (`$uploadHandler->upload($stream)`) that accepts either a resource or a StreamInterface.

Comment: If you MUST pass it through the uploadHandler then you only need the file as a stream and no other additional mechanism. Why is that you cannot use fopen on the source file?

Comment: I need to specify certain request headers

Comment: I have updated the answer with a way to send headers using fopen

Comment: Ah, I did not know that you could do that. Unfortunately the `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);` results in `curl_setopt(): cannot represent a stream of type tcp_socket/ssl as a STDIO FILE*`

Comment: I am sorry, I got the same error too, apparently the remote server must be set appropriately, I though you would avoid this since you mentioned the uploadHandler and would drop the curl but yea... sorry I don't have any other solution for such passing through of the file.

Comment: Oh, I get it now.. Unfortunately it does appear to be downloading the file first. As soon as I pass $fp to the upload handler, I can see in the task manager that the download is spiking for a while, only AFTER that the upload speed is spiking. So it still first downloads it and then uploads it :(